# Facebook Permission not being granted with request

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions, facebook-fql

Registering users in to the application via Facebook with all the permission. But Permissions not being requested during enrollment.

Here will be steps followed

1. Added java script call to Facebook login window with permissions.

   ```
   (function($) {
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
           FB.init({
             appId: '#{settings.facebookAppId}',
             status: true,
             cookie: true,
             xfbml: true,
             oauth: true
           });
         };

   var fbPermissions ="user_about_me,user_activities,user_birthday,user_checkins,user_education_history,user_events,user_groups,user_hometown,user_interests,user_likes,user_location,user_notes,user_online_presence,user_photo_video_tags,user_photos,user_questions,user_relationships,user_relationship_details,user_religion_politics,user_status,user_videos,user_website,user_work_history,email,read_friendlists,read_mailbox,read_requests,read_stream,xmpp_login,manage_friendlists,manage_notifications,user_online_presence,friends_online_presence,publish_stream";

   $(document).on('click', '.linkAccount', function(){
           FB.login(function(res) {
               var authToken =res.authResponse.accessToken;
               var auth = res.authResponse;
           }, { scope: fbPermissions });
       });
   ```

   2. Facebook login window shown
   3. User will be asked for the permission as "will receive the following info: your public profile and email address".
   4. Here Permission asked only for email address, and profile.
   5. There no permission asked for other scope like read_mailbox ...Due to this we getting the error while calling the FQL query.

      SELECT thread_id, body, viewer_id, message_id,source, author_id,     created_time FROM message WHERE thread_id IN (SELECT thread_id FROM thread WHERE folder_id = 1) AND created_time < " + daybeforenow + " ORDER BY created_time DESC"
   6. Getting the error as 
      {"Requires extended permission: read_mailbox","type":"OAuthException","code":298 }
   7. In Users facebook app/settings, approved list showing only for email address, profile.

Trying to fix this issue.no luck. Community help will really appreciated.

Comment: It seems like you are asking for `read_mailbox` permission. Check the `fbPermission` variable. `... user_work_history,email,read_friendlists,read_mailbox,read_requests, ...`

Comment: Please read the Facebook docs first, before using old code examples which will never work with the actual version of the Graph API...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for a very large amount of permissions...some of those don´t exist anymore, some of those will never get approved by Facebook. Only ask for a permission if you really know you need it. FQL is deprecated btw, you should not use it anymore and it will not work in newer Apps.

About permissions in general, you should read the Facebook docs about Login Review: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review

**The permissions most likely don´t work because you are not trying with an App Admin/Developer/Tester and they are not approved.**